# Is there any way to run a command and use its output as g++ compilation flags?

Tags: g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sublimetext, wsl-2

My goal is to be able to compile and run simple C++ programs in WSL2. I want to use WSL's G++ as the compiler. To write the program I am using sublime text for Windows. All my program are stored in Windows filesystem.

This is my sublime build file for C++.

```
"shell_cmd": "wsl g++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=address \"${file}\" -g -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.o\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$", 
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++",
```

Now the problem is when I try to build the code, the sublime variable `${file_path}` passes the Windows file path of my source code to g++ which is installed in WSL2 and g++ is unable to recognize the path and produces errors (as expected).

To overcome this problem I want to use the program called `wslpath` which will convert the Windows file path `C://some_folder` to WSL2 type `/mnt/c/some_folder`.

Now when I try to use `wslpath` in sublime build file, it produces error and doesnot works as expected.

My final sublime build file's `shell_cmd` looks like this

```
"shell_cmd": "wsl g++ -std=c++17 -fsanitize=address $wslpath | \"${file}\" -g -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.o\"",
```

What am I doing wrong in the process or is there something else I can do to achieve the goal?

Comment: Is `wslpath` a program or a variable? If it's a program, try removing the `$` in front of it.

Comment: It is a program [wslpath](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows10v1803/#interoperability)

, and removing $ does not works.